# IF(AND) formula where multiple criteria need to be a match is not working

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, vlookup

I am trying to get a TRUE/FALSE value when 4 criteria match.
On the Sheet3 tab, I would like to have either TRUE or FALSE under col C if the following are a match:
Sheet3!F2 = ActionPlan!B2:B6; Sheet3!F1 = ActionPlan!A2:A6; Sheet3!B2 = ActionPlan!D1:H1; and if there is a "No" in the data range ActionPlan!D2:H6
Please see the example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VBrkVwBa5jXcrQXwB7QGFJhgcbBfjcmCawV7B1YqPcI/edit?usp=sharing
Would anyone be able to help please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the values inside "Action plan" that are "Yes" need to be blank? Because it is easier if the value is not empty, but an actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the empty values inside the "Action Plan" tab to `Yes`. You can use the following formulas:

[image]

*Note:
I added a message in case the Time & date and the location do not match with the information in the "Action plan" tab*

**Question 1:**

```
=IFNA(IF(FILTER('Action plan'!$D$2:$D,'Action plan'!$A$2:$A=$F$1,'Action plan'!$B$2:$B=$F$2)="Yes","True","False"),"Time and location need to match")
```

**Question 2:**

```
=IFNA(IF(FILTER('Action plan'!$E$2:$E,'Action plan'!$A$2:$A=$F$1,'Action plan'!$B$2:$B=$F$2)="Yes","True","False"),"Time and location need to match")
```

**Question 3:**

```
=IFNA(IF(FILTER('Action plan'!$F$2:$F,'Action plan'!$A$2:$A=$F$1,'Action plan'!$B$2:$B=$F$2)="Yes","True","False"),"Time and location need to match")
```

**Question 4:**

```
=IFNA(IF(FILTER('Action plan'!$G$2:$G,'Action plan'!$A$2:$A=$F$1,'Action plan'!$B$2:$B=$F$2)="Yes","True","False"),"Time and location need to match")
```

**Question 5:**

```
=IFNA(IF(FILTER('Action plan'!$H$2:$H,'Action plan'!$A$2:$A=$F$1,'Action plan'!$B$2:$B=$F$2)="Yes","True","False"),"Time and location need to match")
```

The result will be:
[image]

I added a `Data Validation` on my copy to make it easier to change the location and the time.

Like this:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [IF function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [IFNA function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [Filter function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [Data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103)